# Exercise about geometric distribution and passing cars on a highway

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I encountered the following exercise about the geometric distribution:

A student is hitchhiking on the highway. In this season, one twentieth ($ \frac{1}{20} $) of drivers stop to pick up a hitchhiker. What is the probability function of the number of vehicles that the student will see pass before finding a ride? What is the probability that he/she will see at least 6 cars that don't stop?

With the solution:

Let $X$ be the number of cars that pass by until the student is picked up. We are in the presence of a Bernoulli process with:

- a Bernoulli trial corresponds to a passing car. We have a SUCCESS
  when it stops, a FAILURE otherwise.
- in the absence of further
  information, we can assume that the tests are identical and
  independent, and that the probability of a SUCCESS is always $1/20$.

Then, the number of vehicles that pass until one stops $ X $ follows a geometric distribution $g(x;\frac{1}{20})$. In other words, thanks to independence, for $x=1,2,...$,

$$P(X=x)= P(F\cdots F S)= P(F)^{x-1}\times P(S)=\Big(\frac{19}{20}\Big)^{x-1} \frac{1}{20}$$

$$P(X >6)= P(FFFFFF)=P(F)^6=0.735$$

I am confused by the $P(X >6)$ part. What I would do is instead:
$$P(X >6)= 1 - (X \leq6) = 1 - P(X=0) - P(X=1) - \cdots -P(X=6) = 0.682$$

Which one is the correct answer and why?

Comment: Both methods are correct, and give the same answer: $$1-0.05(1+0.95+0.95^2+0.95^3+0.95^4+0.95^5)=0.735.$$ The first method is a little slicker -- note that $X>6$ iff the first $6$ cars don't stop, so it suffices to work out the probability of $6$ fails in a row.

Comment: @jlammy Oh ok, I see. My mistake is that I was considering $P(X=0)$ as well..! Thank you!